# Using the unityEngine in a non-unity-project in C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityscript

If you work with Unity, you have many tools like the Input class to work with. **Is it possible to bring those tools in a non Unity project?**

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, if you have access to the c++ source code. I know Double Fine uses Unity 3D to prototype, and has a pipe line setup to import into their engine.  I don't think just adding the library would work in your case.

However,  if you have a decompiler like Jetbrains dotPeek you can at least look at the C# scripts in Unity and copy their C# code over. But, you'd have to figure out how to reimplent all the pieces of the Input library requiring Unity's C++ code. It's probably just worth looking at to learn about implementing an Input class.

A better bet for this would just be using MonoGame, and developing your own InputManagement system based on the Input class from them.

http://www.monogame.net